# Find Row and Column of value which key in at userform

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, excel-2010

i've a userform for user to keyin their id number into one table. but how can i capture the number of row and column of the id inside the table and delete them.

```
Set f = Worksheets("data").Range("4:4").Find(What:=TextBox2.Value)

If Worksheets("data").Cells(f.Row, f.Column).Value = TextBox2.Value Then
Worksheets("data").TextBox2.Value.Delete
End If
```

thank you very much

Comment: Are you saying you want to basically Loop through the  Column with Ids and delete each Row that has that id ?

Comment: @HolmesIV  i like to loop through the column with IDs and delete that particular cell which contains same id as the input from userform, i keep getting error from my existing code

Comment: Well it seems the line Worksheets("data").TextBox2.Value.Delete , should refer to the Cell not the text box?

Answer (score 3):

`Find()` returns the cell which was found: if no match was made then it returns `Nothing`.

As long as `Find()` finds a match then you can work with it directly: no need to extract `f.Row` and `f.Column` and then turn those back into the same Range. ie `f` and `Worksheets("data").Cells(f.Row, f.Column)` refer to the same object.

```
Set f = Worksheets("data").Range("4:4").Find(What:=TextBox2.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not f Is Nothing Then
    f.Delete
End If
```